# Show every automorphism of a specific group arises the same way.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I have a group $G_n = U(n) \times \mathbb{Z}_n$ with the operation $(a,x)(b,y) = (ab, ay+x) $ where $U(n)$ is the multiplicative group of integers modulo n and $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is the additive group of integers modulo n. Assume n is odd

Then I take a subgroup $H_n = \{(a,b) \in G_n | a = \pm 1\}$.  Now I've shown for $g\in G_n$ and $h \in H_n$the map $\phi_g(h) = ghg^{-1}$ is an automorphism.

How would I go about proving every automorphism of $H_n$ has this form? (The end game is to show $Aut(D_n) \cong G_n$) I would guess that I can take an arbitrary automorphism $\phi'$ and try to show that I can write it as $\phi_g$ for some $g\in G$. Would it be better/easier to try to get a contradiction? Though I'm not seeing how to get a contradiction.

If someone could provided a good approach to tackling this I would appreciate it.

-- Also I'm not allowed Cauchy or Sylow theorems.

Comment: I have not read this very carefully, but I am not convinced it is true when $n$ is even. There is an automorphism of $H_n$ that takes $(1,b)$ to $(1,b)$ and $(-1,0)$ to $(-1,1)$, but this is not of the form $\phi_g$. It's OK when $n$ is odd. You would need to use the fact that (for $n>2$) $\{(1,b) | b \in {\mathbb Z}_n \}$ is the unique cyclic subgroup of $H_n$ of order $n$ and so must be fixed by all automorphisms of $H_n$.

Comment: Sorry I forgot that the problem gives n-odd as an assumption

Comment: @DerekHolt , knowing that ( which I can prove easily) can I then say the an automorphism is determined by where it sends (1,1) and then show that I can write such an automorphism in the required form? I'll also need to show it can't send (1,b) to (-1,b) which I think I've got but those two things should be enough right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in my comment, $\{(1,b) \mid b \in {\mathbb Z}_n\}$ is the unique cyclic subgroup of $H_n$ of order $n$, so any automorphism $\alpha$ of $H_n$ must fix this subgroup. (So it certainly cannot map $(1,b)$ to $(-1,b)$.) But the automorphisms of this cyclic subgroups are all induced by $\phi_g$ for some $g \in U(n)$, so by multiplying $\alpha$ by an appropriate $\phi_g$, we can assume that $\alpha$ centralizes this subgroup. That is $\alpha((1,b))=(1,b)$ for all $b$.

With this assumption, it is true that $\alpha$ is determined by its action on $(1,0)$, and in fact mapping $(1,0)$ to $(1,b)$ really does define an automorphism for all $b \in B$. So far we haven't assumed that $n$ is odd. But when $n$ is odd, all such automorphisms arise as $\phi_g$ for some $g \in {\mathbb Z}_n$ (so they are inner automorphisms of $H_n$).